# If statement without the if?

Tags: c

I'm seeing code that looks like it's trying to do an if statement without the actual if, and I'm confused what it is actually doing. For example,

```
int* value;
int thisValue = 0;
int checkedValue = 1;
*value = thisValue == checkedValue
```

Is this actually doing an if statement without the if?

Comment: Yes, the value of the variable pointed by *value will be 0 if it's a false statement, 1 otherwise.

Comment: It's worth noting that this is terrible code. The more you write *clever* code the more you're going to want to hang yourself the next time you read it.

Comment: Why does this actually work without the if statement?

Comment: Because the comparison takes place *before* the assignment in the order of operations and the assignment assigns the return of the comparison.

Comment: Because there are no conditions, just boolean evaluation. It doesn't need if.

Comment: Haha this is actually legacy code, and I actually do want to hang someone :)

Comment: Don't confuse boolean expressions with if statements.  An if statement takes a boolean expression, but certainly `some_var = some_other_var != 0;` requires no if statement.  Code like `If (something) x = true; else x = false;` is indicative of a novice. As an aside, that code invokes undefined behavior.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just evaluating a boolean expression. and storing it at whatever memory location `value` points to (in your specific snippet `value` isn't allocated so the behavior is undefined).

An `if` allows you to execute different code based on the value of a boolean expression.

For instance,

```
if (a == b) {
  printf("a and b are the same\n");
}
```

Behaves the same as:

```
int same = (a == b);
if (same) {
  printf("a and b are the same\n");
}
```

Though the first is generally cleaner unless you have some reason to want the `same` variable around after the if statement. But the second is closer to the machine instructions that the C code will generate when compiled.

Even though boolean comparison operators like `==` are often used inside of `if` statements, there's nothing that forces them to be used *only* there. You can use the `==` operator anywhere in your code to generate a boolean expression, just like you can use the `+` operator anywhere to generate a numeric expression.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I've never seen this statement used outside of an if statement, so I kinda forgot if could be.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have misunderstood the concept of the `if` conditioned statements.

Usage of the operators like `==`, `>`, `!=`, etc. aren't restricted with the brackets after an `if` or a `while`. They do an operation, just like any other operator does. For example;

```
        // evaluates into...
2 + 3;  // 5
9 / 4;  // 2
7;      // 7
5 == 5; // 1
4 != 5; // 1
9 < 1;  // 0
```

And so on... Boolean operators like equalities and inequalities evaluate into either `0` or `1`. They evaluate into `1` if true, and `0` if false.

Every value that is not `0`, is interpreted as true by the C language. Every non-zero value is true. *Although every non-zero value is true, the result from a boolean operation is strictly either zero or one, not any other number.*

Just like you can use these things outside the `if` parenthesis, you can use other things inside your `if` parenthesis, like this:

```
if ( 2 + 3 ) {
    // this block will happen
    // because 2 + 3 is 5
    // and 5 is non-zero
}

if ( 10 - 6 - 4 ) {
    // this block won't happen
    // because 10 - 6 - 4 is zero
}
```

So, yeah... One last example:

```
6 && 4; // evaluates to 1
0 && 4; // evaluates to 0
```

Answer (score 1):

No, this is not doing an `if` statement. It's just evalating 'thisValue == checkedValue' and assigning it to the variable on the left hand side of the `=` operator.

```
int isTrue = thisValue == checkedVaue;
```

That could be used later in an `if` statement.

```
if ( isTrue )
{
 ...
}
```

That would be equivalent to

```
if ( thisValue == checkedVaue )
{
 ...
}
```

It could also be used in a `while` statement.

```
while ( isTrue )
{
 ...
}
```

Comment: -1 Ignoring the "spirit" of the post. It's fairly clear what the OP is asking, even though it's perhaps phrased in a way that newbie would have phrased it.

Comment: +1 precision in language is critical when learning how to code, and you learn from mistakes.  Also, this shows how such code could _actually be used_, which helps clarify the OP's confusion.

Comment: @IanMallett The OP said he's reading someone else's code and is trying to interpret *what could be an attempt at an if statement*. The correct answer to his question is: YES, that COULD BE what they're trying to do.

Comment: @ciphermagi . . . yes, and the problem is?  The OP writes: "I'm confused what it is actually doing", and this post _shows exactly_ what it's actually doing, by comparing it to code the OP already understands.

Comment: @IanMallett This answer doesn't address what the OP is actually asking. He's very specific in asking whether or not someone could be trying to make a conditional branch using that code. It's *clever* code (and I *hate* so-called "clever" code), but you gave a +1 for precision to someone who answered a question that was never asked. How precise could that possibly be?

Comment: @IanMallett What if that's the inside of a `while(*value){}` loop and no `if()` statement exists anywhere? Then this answer will only serve to confuse.

Comment: @ciphermagi I updated the answer a little bit to address some of your concerns.

Comment: I'll reverse the -1 for the updates, but (and this is personal opinion) I still don't think it's clear enough for a +1.